# Error: duplicate identifier "SYSTEM" - Free Pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I'd doing Free Pascal program, and when I'm importing module `Crt`, showing error:

```
crt.pas(15,9) Error: Dublicate identifier "SYSTEM"
crt.pas(15,9) Error: Dublicate identifier "system"
crt.pas(116,1) Fatal: There were 2 errors compiling modele, stopping
crt.pas(0) Fatal: Compilation aborted
```

Imported modules in program:

```
uses
  Crt,
  Math;
```

I'm using DOS system
On Win10 and Win7 PC compiles fine

Comment: That obviously doesn't usually happen.  Please add  a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your q as well as the first 16 lines of your Crt.Pas.

Comment: @MartynA Crt - it's standart Free Pascal library

Comment: Well, I just entered this code into Lazarus and it compiles without error: `program UsesCrt;  uses Crt, Math; begin end.`.Like I said, you need an mre.

Comment: @MartynA I say that it is **FREE PASCAL STANDART LIBRARY**, but I didn't say about Lazarusm ,ay be this code can compile in Lazarus with errors. On Win10 pc ```Crt``` module works fine, but on DOS system - compiling with errors.

Comment: I just used Lazarus as a convenient IDE to compile FPC   If you get a differnt result on DOS, which isn't mentioned in your q, report it on the FPC support forum: https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?action=forum

Comment: @MartynA [photo](https://ibb.co/X7YYXrZ)

Comment: @MartynA ```Программа завершена, нажмите любую клавишу . . .``` - ```Program is ended, please press any key...```

Comment: It is very unlikely, that this is the standard crt.pas of FPC. The FPC sources do not contain any file called crt.pas (only crt.pp). Please check if you have some stale crt.pas laying (whereever it comes from) around (current dir, compiler dir, unit search pathes).

Comment: @FPK I copy this module from Pascal ABC folder, because when I installed Free Pascal in `options->directories->units` was blank and I don't know what paths need to be writed

Comment: Pascal ABC is unrelated and incompatible. Free Pascal comes with a Crt, and should be in the default installation. Just use it, and move any remaining ABC sources away. Apropos, the error messages look weird with "Dublicate" and "Modele". What is going on there?

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort I don't know why, but this Free Pascal was installed without Crt module

Comment: Then fix that. Borrowing random source won't fix anything. Checking the compiler (and/or IDE) configuration might also help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to reinstall Free Pascal IDE or copy files from working Free Pascal IDE

on Dos no LFN support, for info and this package can be not installed